# How can I make a type of the anonymous function?

Tags: typescript

The function that I want to make a type is below (a part of [scratch-parser](https://github.com/LLK/scratch-parser/blob/72449049504c58825ba18ad9c7206ce2297acafc/index.js#L14-L26)):

```
module.exports = function (input, isSprite, callback) {
    // Unpack the input and further transform the json portion by parsing and
    // validating it.
    unpack(input, isSprite)
        .then(function (unpackedProject) {
            return parse(unpackedProject[0])
                .then(validate.bind(null, isSprite))
                .then(function (validatedProject) {
                    return [validatedProject, unpackedProject[1]];
                });
        })
        .then(callback.bind(null, null), callback);
};
```

I created a type for this function, but the function is anonymous, so I cannot assert the type.

```
declare function scratchParser(
  input: Buffer | string,
  isSprite: boolean,
  callback: (
    err: Error,
    project: ScratchParser.Project | ScratchParser.Sprite,
  ) => void,
): void;
```

How can I assert the type of anonymous function by `module.exports`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `declare` isn't quite right, because that indicates that a function with that name exists in the JavaScript. But what you want is a type for the `module.exports` function to be compared to - or to [satisfy](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html).

Make `scratchParser` a `type`, and indicate that the exported function `satisfies` that type.

```
type scratchParser = (
  input: number | string,
  isSprite: boolean,
  callback: (
    err: Error,
    project: ScratchParser.Project | ScratchParser.Sprite,
  ) => void,
) => void;

module.exports = function (input, isSprite, callback) {
    // Unpack the input and further transform the json portion by parsing and
    // validating it.
    unpack(input, isSprite)
        .then(function (unpackedProject) {
            return parse(unpackedProject[0])
                .then(validate.bind(null, isSprite))
                .then(function (validatedProject) {
                    return [validatedProject, unpackedProject[1]];
                });
        })
        .then(callback.bind(null, null), callback);
} satisfies scratchParser;
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I like `satisfies` keyword! Thank you!